# fetch data from redis (async, serial version vs multiprocessing)

Tags: python, redis

According to Redis docs, redis is single threaded. however i'm having a weird situation fetching data by different approaches.
my redis stores 4 hashes each hash has 50,000 keys, each value 300xfloat32 size.
i try to fetch the data in 3 ways and i get different timing results.
1. serial way:
def fetch_data():
    for i in range(4):
        r.hgetall(hash[i])

using hgetall to fetch the data in serial way, i get the data in ~4 seconds

2. using async await with aioredis, and gather, i get the same timing, which makes sense since the bottleneck is redis, and redis handles 1 request at a time.
3. now this is where things are starting to get weird, im using the multiprocessing python library and i spawn 4 process, each process calls r.hgetall(hash[i]) with different hash and i get the entire data in 1.5seconds

my question is, how is this different than async? how using threads in the client side improves the fetch time?
note that I'm using AWS redis elastic cache in master slave architecture.

Here's my code for case 2 and case 3:
case 2:

```
    async def get_data_v7(intents_group):
       try:
            responses = list()
            buckets = [bucket_1, bucket_2, bucket_3, bucket_4]

            for i in range(len(buckets)):
                responses.append(r.hgetall(buckets[i]))
            await asyncio.gather(*responses)

       except Exception as e:
       print(f"Failed to get data from redis {e}")
```

case 3:

```
def fetch_data_from_redis(bucket_key):
    bucket = r.hgetall(bucket_key)

try:
    process_num = 4
    processes = []
    buckets = [bucket_1, bucket_2, bucket_3, bucket_4]

    for i in range(process_num):
        p = mp.Process(target=fetch_data_from_redis,
                       args=(buckets[i]))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

 except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to get data from redis {e}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Async and thread terms are different, with async you don't have to wait to receive the request, however, all requests will be handled by only one queue and one thread

Elastic Cache is different than Open source Redis, since its multi-threaded

> Availability – Unlike open-source Redis, ElastiCache cluster resizing is designed to run multi-threaded operations at the source shard, allowing slot migration to run on a separate thread from the main I/O thread. This allows ElastiCache to deliver a fully online experience and enables the cluster to serve incoming I/O requests while resizing is in progress.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-elasticache-for-redis-introduces-dynamic-addition-and-removal-of-shards-while-continuing-to-serve-workloads/